# I can't get background image to show up on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
    background: #777 url(foodwine.png) center fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    text-align:center;
}
```

I can't seem to get this background image to show up on IE7 (I'm not sure about other IEs).

I've tried all different kinds of variations and spacings but it just doesn't want to show up in IE.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: I'm using rails to serve the image and it works in firefox/chrome.  I tried specifying the directory with '/images/foodwine.png' but now it doesn't show up on any browser.

http://afternoon-samurai-9254.herokuapp.com/ This is the page I'm working on.

Comment: Use quotes around the URL. Also, some pictures? Does the file even exist?

Comment: @ColeJohnson quote isn't compulsory.

Comment: It's hard to accept an answer when none of them worked :/ I appreciate all the answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: #777 url(foodwine.png) no-repeat center fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *guessing* that the image is in a directory called `images` or something similar? If so, calling it from your root web directory is the safest way to make sure it is referenced properly:

```
background: #777 url('/images/foodwine.png') center fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use margin:0, instead of 0px.
As Cole said add quotes around the image url. I suppose the image exists 'cause you are pointing out explorer, so i think you tried other browsers.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it doesn't seem to work :( I hate internet explorer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have strict doctype for fixed positioning to work on IE7.

```
    <!DOCTYPE htmlPUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: This is really frustrating. I tried using the strict doctype and it still doesn't show up on IE7. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ie7 have a weird behavior (bug?) rendering heavy images (2.3MB in this case), try using  jpg image format instead, a png is normally used to support transparency which I dont see it in this case.